# Not able to set text in input field from json response

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a form in which I have to fill data after I have got a json object from httpGet in javascript.

```
$("#getDetails").click(function() {

    $.get("/servlet",{
        mID : 5
    })
   .done(function(data) {
        $("#input1").val(data["some key"]);
        $("#input2").val(data.name);
        $("#input3").val("directvalue");

    });    
});
```

In the above 3 fields, only input3 gets filled with "directvalue".

Is there some problem in accessing json object or in setting value of input fields.

Note: the json object contains keys with spaces like "some key":"some value"

**edit:**

When I tried `Object.keys(data)[index]` to access the object field, I got `Uncaught TypeError: Object.keys called on non-object`

Comment: what value you are getting in "data"? put alert and check

Comment: Can you show your server side code populating the object

Comment: Agreed with Neel, but if you're in Chrome try console.log(data)

Comment: @Vishal - Try this ` $("#input2").val(data.d.name);`

Comment: server side is perfectly ok: its returning {
  "Name": "my name",
  "my address": "23, round street",
  "Description": "PM Speech at Red Fort on Indep Day 2014"
} as a json object

Comment: why do you give spaces in key? rather user `my_address`

Comment: Not in my control.. But that should not be a problem i guess

Comment: @Vishal Have you tried like this `Object.keys(data)[index]`?

Comment: Have you checked the capital letters? `data["name"]` may return undefined, but `data["Name"]` not.

Comment: @Jayanth it returns `Uncaught TypeError: Object.keys called on non-object `

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
   $("#getDetails").click(function () {
        $.get("/servlet", { 
            mID: 5 })
        .success(function (data) {
            $("#input1").val(data.d.somekey);
            $("#input2").val(data.d.name);
            $("#input3").val("directvalue");
        });
    });
```

Comment: @vishal - you can not use `space` in Properties. it's a variable or Properties. - can you plz show the class  or server side code that how do you populate the object.

Comment: we can use space in keys; I have implemented the client side code in java for android as well. there its working perfectly well.

Comment: @vishal - can you plz put here the server side code so we can help you in better way ..... how you populate the `data` object from the server side coding.

Answer (score 0):

In the comments, you say it's returning this object:

```
{ 
  "Name": "my name",
  "my address": "23,round street",
  "Description": "PM Speech at Red Fort on Indep Day 2014"
}
```

Try:

```
$("#input2").val(data.Name);
```

Comment: what about `my address`?

Comment: @Jayanth `data["my address"]`

Answer (score 0):

When I did `console.out(data)`, it was printing a json object.

But when I tried `Object.keys(data)[index]` to access the object field, I got `Uncaught TypeError: Object.keys called on non-object`.

This means that `data`itself was not a json object.

So I got a hint that server was giving a string in which json object was written. I had to simply parse the json object from the `data` string.

Following is the working code:

```
$("#getDetails").click(function() {

    $.get("/servlet",{
        mID : 5
    })
   .done(function(data) {
   var dataObj=JSON.parse(data);
        $("#input1").val(dataObj["some key"]);
        $("#input2").val(dataObj.name);


    });    
});
```